# How to send a status bar notification on bootup based on a preference checkbox from a different activity?

Tags: java, android, xml, broadcastreceiver

I may have asked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683959/broadcast-receiver-check-a-checkbox-preference-state-on-bootup-then-send-a-notif) before but i'm still having issues with my broadcast receiver being started when the phone boots up. So what I need to know is how to do a basic broadcast receiver that sends a status bar notification based on a checkbox preference from a different activity weather it's checked or not and how i'm suppose to list it in the manifest file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the BroadcastReceiver and the Activity are in the same package, then you can:

1. Create a BOOT_COMPLETED BroadcastReceiver (see http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/06/start-service-at-boot/)
2. Read the preference in the receiver: I generally use `SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);` in the receiver to get the global preferences object.
3. Use `getSystemService` to get the NotificationManager (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSystemService%28java.lang.String%29 and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html).
4. Show the notification using the NotificationManager.

Comment: Thx for the quick answer this looks like it will help a lot.

Comment: How are you suppose to use the `getSystemService`?

Comment: It is a method on the context you are passed to in the `onReceive` method.