# android get preferences from broadcast receiver

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, preferences

Well, i am an Android newbie. I am trying to write an application which has one activity which starts another activity (Preference Activity), and one BoradcastReceiver. They are all in three different files. My question is: How to share Preferences betweens these components, e.g. how to read preferences that are set in Preference Activity from Broadcast Receiver?

Comment: This questions is likely an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614719/how-do-i-get-the-sharedpreferences-from-a-preferenceactivity-in-android

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have asked this same exact question before and here is the code I used:

```
public class BootupReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final boolean BOOTUP_TRUE = true;
private static final String BOOTUP_KEY = "bootup";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if(getBootup(context)) {
        NotificationManager NotifyM = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification Notify = new Notification(R.drawable.n,
                "NSettings Enabled", System.currentTimeMillis());

        Notify.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
        Notify.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

        RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.notification);
        Notify.contentView = contentView;

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, Toggles.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        Notify.contentIntent = contentIntent;

                    int HELO_ID = 00000;

        NotifyM.notify(HELLO_ID, Notify);
    }

    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent();
    serviceIntent.setAction("com.leozar100.myapp.NotifyService");
    context.startService(serviceIntent);
}

public static boolean getBootup(Context context){
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getBoolean(BOOTUP_KEY, BOOTUP_TRUE);
}
}
```

The service that I start does nothing I just initiate one because I think it just helps the broadcast receiver work. Also this broadcast receiver is registered in my manifest like so:

```
<receiver android:name=".BootupReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Which starts on bootup requiring the permission `android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED`

Reference to my question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683959/broadcast-receiver-check-a-checkbox-preference-state-on-bootup-then-send-a-noti)

P.S. Welcome to stackoverflow

Comment: Thank you Leozar100. Your answer was very helpful!